# How to use http calls with roboelectric or junit in Android?

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, okhttp, androidhttpclient

I have the following Test class which I need to retrieve information from a json in an API using OKhttp (if there is no way to do this with OKHttp is there any other recommended way?), but it isn't working I keep failing my test where `openRestaurants != null`:

```
@Config(constants = HomeActivity.class, sdk= 16, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RestaurantFindTest{

    private String jsonData = null;
    private JSONObject jsonResponse;
    private JSONArray openRestaurants;


    String url = "http://example/api/find/restaurants";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        Response response = null;

        try {
            response = call.execute();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                jsonData = response.body().string();

            } else {
                jsonData = null;
                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                openRestaurants = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("open");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testGetOpenRestaurants() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(openRestaurants != null);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonData = null;
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonData);
openRestaurants = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("open");
```

You create a new JSONObject passing in null as a constructor argument
 => it will be empty 
=> `jsonResponse.getJSONArray("open");` will fail.


Probably you wanted something like this:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    jsonData = response.body().string();
    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    openRestaurants = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("open");
} else {
    // handle failure
}
```